# Eventstore UnknownError: Could not recognize BadRequest

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, event-handling

I'm currently using Eventstore, and I'm receiving the following error:  `Could not recognize BadRequest`;

from:

```
game process tick failed UnknownError: Could not recognize BadRequest
    at unpackToCommandError (\node_modules\@eventstore\db-client\dist\streams\appendToStream\unpackError.js:53:12)
    at ClientDuplexStreamImpl.<anonymous> (\node_modules\@eventstore\db-client\dist\streams\appendToStream\batchAppend.js:38:66)
```

For some reason, it seems like it is something with my handler:

```
async function   gameProcessPush(channel,event) {
    console.log("pushing:",event);
    try {
        console.log("trying to append..:",event);

           await client.appendToStream("factory",[event]);
           console.log("appending to stream");
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("game process tick failed",e);
            throw  {live: false, code: 26, event: event}
        }
        console.log("game processing...");

}
```

*What am I doing wrong here?*

rest of debug code:

```
processing factory failed {
  live: false,
  code: 26,
  event: { type: 'factory-creation', sub: 'sub-factory', userid: 1 }
}
result in :  undefined
```

Full code:

```
import { streamNameFilter } from "@eventstore/db-client";
import { createSecureServer } from "http2";
import { runMain } from "module";
import { eventNames, mainModule } from "process";
import { arrayBuffer } from "stream/consumers";
import { SubscriptionInfo } from "./generated/persistent_pb";
import { AllStreamPosition } from "./generated/shared_pb";

const {EventStoreDBClient, FORWARDS, StreamNotFoundError, jsonEvent, START, END, excludeSystemEvents, eventTypeFilter} = require("@eventstore/db-client");

  
  const client = new EventStoreDBClient({
    endpoint: "localhost:2113",
}, {
    insecure: true,
});

    interface creationFactory {
        userid: string,
        location: [number,number,number],
        name: string
        type: string,
    }

class Factory {


    public async create(creation : creationFactory) {
        console.log("creating new factory.....",creation);   
        const NewFactoryEvent = CreateEvent("factory-creation",{userid: 1, sub: "sub-factory"})
        try {
            console.log("creating newfac",NewFactoryEvent);
            await gameProcessPush("factory",NewFactoryEvent)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("processing factory failed",error);
        }
    }


}

function CreateEvent(type,data) {
    return  {type: type, sub: data.sub,
        userid: data.userid,
        
    }
}

async function   gameProcessPush(channel,event) {
    console.log("pushing:",event);
    try {
        console.log("trying to append..:",event);

           await client.appendToStream("factory",[event]);
           console.log("appending to stream");
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("game process tick failed",e);
            throw  {live: false, code: 26, event: event}
        }
        console.log("game processing...");

}


//new Factory().create({userid: "1", location: [1,1,1], name: "test bank", type: "BANK"});
async function test() {
    try {
       await  new Factory().create({
            userid: "1",
            location: [0,0,0],
            name: "test",
            type: "factory",
        });
          
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("factory creation faileD");
    }
}

test().catch((e) => {console.log("test failed",e)}).then(function (data) {
console.log("result in : ",data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Context

**EventData**

An EventStore `event` must be a `EventData` object, that has, at least, two properties:

- `type`, basically a string that defines the event's type.
- `data`, that is the payload and must be a *byte array*, usually a JSON, serialized object.

**appendToStream**

EventStore `appendToStream` usage:

```js
await client.appendToStream(STREAM_NAME, event);
```

**Related docs**

- [Creating an event](https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/#creating-an-event)
- [Appending events](https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/appending-events.html#append-your-first-event)

### Issues

There are two potential issues in your code:

1. You are trying to append an `Array` as event (`[event]`), instead of a EventData object.
2. The `event` structure does not correspond with an EventData object, as reflected by your debug log and your `CreateEvent` method.

### Possible solution

Process your input event to create a valid `EventData` object and then append it:

```
async function gameProcessPush(channel, event) {
  try {
    const eventData = jsonEvent({
      type: event.type,
      data: {
        sub: event.sub,
        userid: event.userid,
      },
    });
    await client.appendToStream("factory", eventData);
  } catch (e) {
    throw { live: false, code: 26, event: event };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you've read the documentation of **EventStore**.

Refer if you missed something - https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/#appending-events

Try changing `[event]` to `event`

```
async function   gameProcessPush(channel,event) {
    console.log("pushing:",event);
    try {
        console.log("trying to append..:",event);

           await client.appendToStream("factory",event);
           console.log("appending to stream");
        } catch(e) {
            console.log("game process tick failed",e);
            throw  {live: false, code: 26, event: event}
        }
        console.log("game processing...");

}
```

See if it works